# regex characters replace multiple characters

Tags: regular-expression, gvim

what is the most efficient regex (vim/perl) to replace 10 'a' characters with 1 'c' character followed by 100 'b' characters?

this does not work:
:%s/a{10}/\=repeat('c',1)\=repeat('b',100)/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `:%s/a\{10}/\=repeat('c',1).repeat('b',100)/g`

Comment: even shorter: %s/a\{10}/\='c'.repeat('b',100)

Comment: the 'dot' concatenation did the trick.